# Why isn't the webpack binary installed via package.json?

Tags: npm, webpack, npm-install

webpack is in my package.json. When I run `npm install`, the library gets installed in ./node_modules but not the binary. When I run `npm install -g webpack`, the binary gets installed at the system level.

Is there a way to have `npm install` also install the binary?

Comment: so that i can invoke webpack and build my assets

Answer (score -1):

The answer was I needed to change

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "alt": "0.17.7",
```

to...

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "alt": "0.17.7",
```